# Azure Cloud storage with Windows Azure Websites

Tags: azure, ravendb, azure-storage

Is it possible to use Azure Cloud Storage with Windows Azure websites?

All of the code samples for Cloud Storage that I have found use Azure Cloud Services with a Web role.

I am using RavenDB embedded so I need Azure Cloud Storage, right?

I am currently using Azure Cloud Services + Azure Cloud Storage.

PS. this is for a small personal website with almost no traffic.

Comment: There are perf implications for ravendb in azure.  There is still debate in the community on what best practices actually are.  Please search for Azure in the [RavenDB google group](https://groups.google.com/group/ravendb).  If you still have questions, then post there.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Azure Cloud Storage (Blob, Tables etc.) are ordinary network service which uses REST protocol under the hood. The Cloud Storage services can be accessed from Azure Cloud services as well as Azure Websites. Also you can use Azure Cloud Storage from you on-premiss applications (however, due to network latency it might be a bit slower than from the cloud).

Azure Cloud Storage API (which you probably mentioned) seems to be the best option to use when on Azure Websites.

Please note that the same applies to Azure SQL - it can be used from Azure Cloud service as well as Azure Website (including on-premiss applications)